# Batch file to copy files based on characters in filename and execute remotely

Tags: batch-file

I need a batch file to copy files from a single folder to multiple folders, based on filename. The files are of the form G11231-416546-555-65465.mp3 where G  do not matter, but 11231 are 5 character codes. For example files G34353-5454-545-454.mp3 G76776-656-656-65.mp3 should be copied to folders 34353 and 76776 respectively, and these folders will be created by the script.
and also it must be executed remotely

I've seen example scripts using the FOR /f, but cannot see how to parse the file, examine characters variable characters, then create the folder, and copy the files.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for %%f in (*.mp3) do (
   set filename=%%f
   set folder=!filename:~1,5!
   if not exist !folder! md !folder!
   copy !filename! !folder!
)
```

Comment: hi, but how to run this script for the mp3 files located in some different location and i want to run it local

Comment: like the mp3 files located in \\share1\folder1 and the batch script i am executing should be located in \\share2\folder2 the hw i can modify this script.